# How to search for the values in a list based on a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dateframe with the various countries in the first column. I need to filter those which belong to EU. I've used the list with EU countries and this code:
df=df[df['COUNTRY'].isin(EU)]

My question is, how can I get the names of coutries which are in the list but not in my data frame (in order to know which EU countries are missing in the dataset)?

Comment: `[country for country in EU if country not in df["COUNTRY"].unique()]`?

Comment: set(EU) - set(df['COUNTRY'])